# Access Violation when trying to run MIT Scheme under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, access-violation, mit-scheme

I've been trying to install MIT Scheme under a 64-bit Windows 10 installation, however whenever I try to start the program I get the following error message:

> >>The system has trapped within critical section "band load".
>
> >>The trap is an ACCESS_VIOLATION trap.
>
> >>Successful recovery is unlikely.

Then I'm presented with the option to try to recover, but the program then crashes with another ACCESS_VIOLATION.

I have already tried installing it in different directories and drives, setting the heap size, running with and without `--edit` and running it in multiple compatibility modes.

GDB reports this:

> Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x779f2a4c in win32u!NtUserMessageCall () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\win32u.dll

Is there a way to fix this problem or should I just not bother and try another implementation?

Thank you for your help!